# Python dictionary check if the values match with other key values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a python dictionary with a structure like :-

```
mydict = {'2018-08' : [32124,4234,23,2323,32423,342342],
          '2018-07' : [13123,23424,2,3,4343,4232,2342],
          '2018-06' : [1231,12,12313,12331,3123131313,434546,232]}
```

I want to check if any value in the values of key `'2018-08'` match with any values of other keys. is there a short way to write this?

Comment: Edited your question to change `dict` to `mydict`. It's always a bad idea to use a variable name that masks a built-in python type

Comment: have you made an attempt of this yourself? can you show what you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean match? All the same values? Some of the same values? Please create an [mcve] with a desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over your expected values of `mydict`, and then for each of them check if its present in any of the values of the dictionary

You can use the idiom `if item in list` to check if item `item` is present in the list `list`

```
expected_values = mydict['2018-08']
found = False
for expected in expected_values:
  for key in mydict:
    if expected in mydict[key]:
      found = True
      break
```

Take into account that is a brute force algorithm and it may not be the optimal solution for larger dictionaries

Comment: unless the lists are ordered somehow (i.e. largest to smallest or alphabetical) I don't think there is a way aside from brute forcing

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, so I am assuming that you want the values in the target month (e.g. 2018-08) that are contained somewhere within the other months.

Sets are much faster for testing membership compared to list iteration.

```
target = '2018-08'
s = set()
for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
    if k != target:
        s.update(v)
matches = set(mydict[target]) & s
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to create a long list

```
import itertools
for key,value in mydict.items():
    temp_dict = mydict.copy()
    temp_dict.pop(key)
    big_value_list=list(itertools.chain(*temp_dict.values()))
    print(key, set(value) & set(big_value_list))
```

Dry run by changing your provided inputs

```
mydict = {'2018-08' : [32124,4234,23,2323,32423,342342],
          '2018-07' : [13123,23424,2,3,4343,4232,2342],
          '2018-06' : [1231,12,12313,12331,3123131313,434546,232,342342,2342]}
```

Output:

```
('2018-08', set([342342]))
('2018-07', set([2342]))
('2018-06', set([342342, 2342]))
```